# Auto-populating Select Field via jQuery's Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I'm coding in classic ASP, and using ADO to access my database. I have two select fields, namely:

```
<select name="NBSCourse" class="NBSCourse"></select>
<select name="IndexNo" class="IndexNo"></select>
```

For "NBSCourse", the option fields are being populated via SQL request, listing distinct results of all available course codes. I would like to populate the next select field "IndexNo", based on the selected value of "NBSCourse".

At the moment, I've tried the following: passing the selected field for nbsCourseid to the ASP file "indexnodrop

```
$("select.NBSCourse").change(function () {
var nbsCourseid;
nbsCourseid = $("select.NBSCourse").val();

 $.ajax({url:"indexnodropdown.asp?q="+nbsCourseid,success:function(result) { 

    $("select.IndexNo").html(result);

}})

 })
```

In indexnodrop.asp , I've sent in to execute the script into the database.

```
dim selectedcourseID
selectedcourseID = Request.querystring("q")

oCmd.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT IndexNo FROM NBSCourse WHERE CourseId='" &  selectedcourseID & "'"
Set oRS = oCmd.Execute() 

If Not oRS.EOF Then 
response.write("<option value='" & oRS("IndexNo") & "'>" & oRS("IndexNo") & "</option>")
End If
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your sql is subject to injection attacks as represented here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("select[name=NBSCourse]").change(function () {
  var nbsCourseid;
  nbsCourseid = this.value; // or $(this).value();
   $.ajax({url:"indexnodropdown.asp?q="+nbsCourseid,success:function(result) { 
     $("select[name=IndexNo]").html(result);
  }};
});
```

You can't use

`select.NBSCourse` because `.` notation used for access `class`, but you've used `name` attribute.

#### According to comment

if you use `class`, instead of `name` then you can use

```
$("select.NBSCourse").change(function () {
  var nbsCourseid;
  nbsCourseid = this.value; // or $(this).value();
   $.ajax({url:"indexnodropdown.asp?q="+nbsCourseid,success:function(result) { 
     $("select.IndexNo").html(result);
  }};
})
```

Comment: Not quite. I believe it's a problem with ASP script.

Comment: @kosherjellyfish If this does not solve your issue, please provide more details on where your failure occurs - does the change event fire? Does the value reach the back end?  Is the value returned but not placed in the option list? etc.

Comment: I managed to get it! The problem was with my connections string to the database.