# Removal of <% %> and %><% in Classic ASP when there is nothing between them causes the web page to crash. Why is that?

Tags: asp-classic

I am working with Classic ASP and I have a need to make the code simpler. In an effort to do what is similar to what we see here: [Auto-populating Select Field via jQuery's Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984901/auto-populating-select-field-via-jquerys-ajax) where we use ajax to populate a select filed, we load the contents of a area with by using a separate asp file to load. I assume that the loaded file is free of <% markings. While testing the commands contained in that file I am in the process of removing those marks. Why would removing a %><% mark (where it is just a close followed by an open) throw an error? And why would it be necessary to have something like %>"<% where it is just one character?

The reason why I posted an image of the code block was because the %> and %> symbols were highlighted by color in such a way as to better visualize what was going on.

Here is the code block:

```
<%
    Function FunctionName(name, selection) 
%>
    <select name = "<%= name%>"><% 
    Set RTConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    RTConn.Open("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=three4me;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=DATABASE;Data Source=SERVER")
    Set RT = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    sqlQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT id, Replace(Name, '  ', ' ') AS Name, Num, Address, City, State FROM RedactedTablename WHERE active = 1 OR ID = '" & selection & "' ORDER BY Replace(Name, '  ', ' '), State, City, Num"
    RT.Open sqlQuery, RTConn, 3, 3
    Do While Not RT.EOF

    response.write "<option value=" & RT.Fields("id")
        %>" <%   
        if cstr(RT.Fields("id")) = selection  then   
                response.write " selected "
        elseif (selection = "" OR selection = "0") AND trim(RT.Fields("Name")) = "NA" then 
            response.write " selected "
        end if
    %>><%=RT.Fields("Name")%><% 
    if not RT.Fields("Name") = "NA" AND  not RT.Fields("Name") = "NA" then 
        response.write " (" & RT.Fields("City") & ", " & RT.Fields("State") & ") - " & RT.Fields("Num") 
    end if
    %>
    response.write"</option>"
<%
    RT.MoveNext
    Loop
    RT.Close
    RTConn.Close %>
    </select>
    <%
End function

%>
```

Comment: It’s because the `<%` and `%>` denote the start and end of code and anything outside of that is just plain old HTML.

Comment: Also, please don’t post images of code (you’ve been around long enough to know that’s not accepted). Use the code blocks provided in the [edit] to paste in the problem code.

Comment: @user692942 right but there is nothing between the %> and the <% so if that is the case then logically one should be able to remove both of them.,  I know that there should be just plain HTML but what if there is nothing between them at all and if I remove them the program crashes.

Comment: It depends what is before and after each marker, just because there is no HTML between them doesn’t mean it will be syntactically correct. It’s hard to judge without some sample code, please [edit] the question and paste in a code block that shows the problem.

Comment: @user692942 sample code added.

Comment: It’s because `<%= ` is a special shorthand way of writing `Response.Write` but it is only valid with an end `%>` tag, so you can’t just remove the end tag and not expect a syntax error.

Comment: Also, `response.write"</option>"` is outside the server code block

Answer (score 1):

The end tag that was removed was paired with a start tag of `<%=` not `<%` which has caused the syntax error.

The reason is `<%=` is a shorthand form of `Response.Write` and has to be paired with a closing `%>` tag.

Acceptable:

```html
<a href="<%= link_href %>"><%= link_label %></a>
```

Invalid syntax:

```html
<a href="<%= link_href"><%= link_label</a>
```

Also, there are other issues with the code, for example, [@Flakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1682881/flakes) pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69384137/removal-of-and-in-classic-asp-when-there-is-nothing-between-them-caus#comment122667681_69384137) that `response.write"</option>"` is not located within Classic ASP preprocessor tags (`<%` and `%>`).
While this won't cause a syntax error it will cause the line to be interpreted as HTML and will be output to the client as is.